# Any book for learning to correctly find out complexity of one's algorithm?

Tags: reference-request

Suppose we have designed an Algorithm and we want to find out its complexity. I am looking for a book which mainly focuses on finding out complexity of algorithms rather than introducing me to different search, sort, and ... algorithms.

Answer (score 2):

Simply pick up any algorithms book out there, they will all take you through these things.  What you are describing is essentially the algorithms (and computational complexity) field.

The most popular books are *Algorithms* by Sedgewick and Wayne, which is free for download, the CLRS Introduction to Algorithms, and the epic Art of Computer Programming by Knuth.

Comment: None of the above books actually focus on Computing Complexity of algorithms. They mainly focus on ritual materials told in an Algorithm class with heavy focus on Sorting, search and other algorithms. What I am asking is whether there is any textbook solely focusing on complexity of algorithms? For instance I have made an algorithm for doing a particular job, how should I find out complexity of it?

Comment: Quite frankly, you just need to count the number of operations your algorithm does as a function of its input.  This is what you practice when doing complexity analysis of sorting and searching, and not least knowing how many "instructions" different data structure operations use.

Comment: That's easier said than done.

Comment: That is absolutely right!